# make networkmanager not prompt for password after failed connection?

Tags: wifi, networkmanager

While it's only an intermittent annoyance, occasionally I'm on a flaky wifi network, and each time networkmanager reconnects, it asks for the wifi password. This wouldn't be a huge issue, but the password is not pre-filled-in, so I have to go lookup up the password elsewhere, then enter it. If I hit cancel, it won't try to reconnect, and if I just hit "ok", then it will store the blank password over what it already has!

Is there any way to mark a connection as "I'm sure this is the right password!" so it will just try again (perhaps with exponential backoff) if the connection fails?

Thanks!!

Comment: I use Linux Mint (on my laptop) & OpenSuSE (on my desktop)

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue `gnome-keyring` solved it.

[Networkmanager doesn't automatically ask for password for new network](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142066)

Comment: Federico is right. It's work. I tried this two month ago.